# How to fix error in installing NLPre in Anaconda?

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda, spacy

I am new relatively new to Python and working with Anaconda and I attempting to install NLPre using the following commands within the Anaconda command prompt:

```
pip install nlpre
```

The install hangs when installing build dependencies for spacy 2.1.0 and I get the following long output:

```
Collecting spacy==2.1.0
  Using cached spacy-2.1.0.tar.gz (27.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
      Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
        Using cached cymem-2.0.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
        Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
        Using cached murmurhash-1.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (18 kB)
      Collecting thinc==7.0.0.dev6
        Using cached thinc-7.0.0.dev6.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
        Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting thinc_gpu_ops<0.1.0,>=0.0.1
        Using cached thinc_gpu_ops-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
      Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
        Using cached numpy-1.23.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
      Collecting wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0
        Using cached wrapt-1.10.11-py3-none-any.whl
      Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
        Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
        Using cached tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
      Collecting six<2.0.0,>=1.10.0
        Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
      Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
        Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.5
        Using cached srsly-1.0.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (177 kB)
      Collecting colorama
        Using cached colorama-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: thinc, preshed, blis
        Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [176 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\thinc
       #I deleted some repetitive copy steps to save characters
        copying thinc\extra\search.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\thinc\extra
        running build_ext
        building 'thinc.linalg' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\thinc
        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\thinc_528ca1a5c727434bb1c9be6a9cf85be1\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpthinc/linalg.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\thinc/linalg.obj /Ox /EHsc
        linalg.cpp
        thinc/linalg.cpp(201): warning C4804: '/': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation
        thinc/linalg.cpp(1910): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to '__pyx_t_5thinc_8typedefs_weight_t', possible loss of data
        thinc/linalg.cpp(2350): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to '__pyx_t_5thinc_8typedefs_weight_t', possible loss of data
        thinc/linalg.cpp(2397): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to '__pyx_t_5thinc_8typedefs_weight_t', possible loss of data
        thinc/linalg.cpp(2564): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to '__pyx_t_5thinc_8typedefs_weight_t', possible loss of data
        thinc/linalg.cpp(3232): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to '__pyx_t_5thinc_8typedefs_weight_t', possible loss of data
        thinc/linalg.cpp(3872): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        thinc/linalg.cpp(3897): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        thinc/linalg.cpp(3916): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        thinc/linalg.cpp(3927): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
        Running setup.py clean for thinc
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [42 lines of output]
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          warnings.warn(
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\preshed
        running build_ext
        building 'preshed.maps' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed
        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
        maps.cpp
        preshed/maps.cpp(5728): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5740): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5749): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5755): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5761): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(5767): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
        preshed/maps.cpp(6129): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
        preshed/maps.cpp(6145): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for preshed
        Running setup.py clean for preshed
        Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [33 lines of output]
        BLIS_COMPILER? None
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
        copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
        running build_ext
        C:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\blis_f6044dd4d07f48548964902c86472263\bin\cythonize.py:58: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
          if LooseVersion(cython_version) < LooseVersion('0.19'):
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\blis_f6044dd4d07f48548964902c86472263\blis\cy.pxd
          tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\blis_f6044dd4d07f48548964902c86472263\blis\py.pyx
          tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
        Processing blis\cy.pyx
        Processing blis\py.pyx
        error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
        msvc
        py_compiler msvc
        {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
        clang -c C:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\blis_f6044dd4d07f48548964902c86472263\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmp_u4panl6\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-xwlhseua\blis_f6044dd4d07f48548964902c86472263\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
        Running setup.py clean for blis
      Failed to build thinc preshed blis
      Installing collected packages: wrapt, wasabi, srsly, plac, cymem, wheel, six, setuptools, preshed, numpy, murmurhash, Cython, colorama, tqdm, thinc_gpu_ops, blis, thinc
        Running setup.py install for preshed: started
        Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [13 lines of output]
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          warnings.warn(
        running install
        C:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        running build
        running build_py
        running build_ext
        building 'preshed.maps' extension
        "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\hudsonad\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tppreshed/maps.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\preshed/maps.obj /Ox /EHsc
        maps.cpp
        c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'preshed/maps.cpp': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      preshed

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I have installed MS Visual C++ build tools and I still get this error.  I haven't been able to find anything about how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the `.cpp` files provided in the package `.tar.gz` release not being compatible with some versions of python that are newer than the package. When this package was released the most recent version of python was 3.7.

The easiest solution is to use an older version of python, in particular one where you can install everything from compiled wheels with `pip` rather than having to compile anything, like python 3.7.

If you really want to use python 3.9, then you can try installing directly from the github archive for each repo / version tag, which will use a newer version of cython to generate files that are compatible with python 3.9:

```
pip install -r cython "cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0"
pip install https://github.com/explosion/preshed/archive/v2.0.1.zip
```

You may have to repeat this for all the other requirements that have the same error: 1) install the requirements for this release (find `requirements.txt` in the repo at this tag), 2) `pip install` from the repo for this tag, either from a local clone or from this kind of archive URL.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to checkt the compatible python versions. If you check the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/nlpre/), you will see python 3.6 listed as the only one, so simply use the power of conda to create an environment and install there:

```
conda create -n newEnv python=3.6
conda activate newEnv
pip install nlpre
```